# Javascript - Does accessing objects through a reference incur much of a performance hit?

Tags: javascript, performance, reference

```
function Obj()
{
    this.prop = { a: 1, b: 2 };

    this.access();
    access(this.prop);
}

Obj.prototype.access = function()
{
    // accessing 'this.prop' directly
}

function access(property)
{
    // accessing 'this.prop' through local reference 'property'
}
```

How much of a performance hit is incurred when accessing `Obj.prop` indirectly through an object reference (as seen in the global `access()` function) vs directly (as seen in `Obj`'s `access()` method), and why?

Comment: There's no difference between your two cases. Whether it's `this` or `foo`, you're still doing `x.y`.

Comment: @ssube My understanding is as follows, and is explained further at the following page: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/data-locality.html - A reference points to data in some arbitrary location in memory. Accessing that data indirectly will almost always produce a 'cache miss' as it is not contiguous with the local data. The result is that the CPU stalls while it waits for the data to be retrieved, which incurs a performance hit. Does this apply to Javascript also, or are there optimizations in place for this?

Comment: @sookie: This kind of optimisation is done, if at all, only by the compiler/interpreter in javascript. But no, there's always the same number of reference lookups done here, regardless whether you use an intermediate variable or not, so it doesn't make a difference. And when you repeat them, caches (either in the compiled code or the cpu itself) will take care of this.

Comment: JS doesn't use traditional references or pointers, plus having an entire layer of optimizations around creating predictable structures for common objects.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the information. Much appreciated. Could you add those details to your answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 0):

None, really.

```
var p = obj.prop
p.a
```

and

```
obj.prop.a
```

are exactly equivalent, the local variable can be optimised out. In the case of a function call (`access(this.prop)`) the parameter probably cannot be optimised away until the function is inlined, but still there is hardly any difference.

It might make a difference if `p` is accessed multiple times instead of accessing `obj.prop` multiple times, but even that is optimised fine in modern engines.

Any performance difference will be negligible. But javascript is not a language where you'd do such microoptimisations anyway - if you write standard code, the engine optimises it for your quite well.